# How to create single textfield class for email and phone in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created profile setup page where I have name, email and phone text field. I have created single textfield class where I take controller, title as parameter. How can I create a validator by checking the email or a phone in a single textfield class.
This is how I created in view class

```
ProfileTextFormField(
                        controller: _mobileNumberController,
                        title: "Mobile No",
                        hintText: "",
                      ),
                      ProfileTextFormField(
                        controller: _emailIdController,
                        title: "Email Id",
                        hintText: "",
                      ),
```

Below is the class for textfield where I intake input. I need to validate here for email, or phone.

```
class ProfileTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  final title;
  final hintText;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  const ProfileTextFormField(
      {Key? key,
      required this.title,
      required this.hintText,
      required this.controller})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3.0, left: 24),
          child: Text(
            title,
            style: AppTextStyle.latoMedium(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: AppColorPallet.profileText),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0, right: 24, left: 24),
            child: TextField(
              controller: controller,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: AppColorPallet.app_green_natural,
                  ),
                ),
                errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: AppColorPallet.app_Red,
                  ),
                ),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: AppColorPallet.app_green_natural,
                  ),
                ),
                disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: AppColorPallet.app_green_natural,
                  ),
                ),
                hintText: hintText,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: could you please add your code too?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass validator as parameter too.Try  this:

```
class TextFormFieldWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final String? title;
  final String? Function(String?)? validator;

  TextFormFieldWidget({
    required this.controller,
    this.validator,
    this.title,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: controller,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: title,
      ),
      validator: validator,
    );
  }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
TextFormFieldWidget(
              controller: TextEditingController(),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'empty value';
                }
                return null;
              })
```